# how can get object type who returned from a function

Tags: typescript

I want to auto-type className, but i don't know how

```
const createClassName = (arr:Array<string>) => {
return Object.fromEntries(arr.map((e,i) => {
    const first = i === 0 ? '' : `${arr[0]}__`
    return [e.replace(/(\b|-)\w/g, function(m) {
        if(e[0] === m){
            return m
        } 
      return m.toUpperCase().replace(/-/,'');
    }),first + e]
}))
```

}

```
const clsArr = [
'admin-login-page',
'dashboard',
'form',
'form-container',
'fieldset',
'input-label',
'link',
]
const className = createClassName(clsArr) // how get type?
```

I tried do something like this, but it does'nt work

```
type c = typeof className
const z:c = className
```

I need autocomplete and when i do something like this className.blabla throw error like this in className havent blabla only [dashboard,from,etc]

something like this

```
const obj = {
    1:1,
    2:2
}

type Z = typeof obj

const obj2:Z = obj

obj2.[ `have only`,`1`,`2`]
```

Comment: auto type class name ?

Comment: className type is determined by createClassName function. In your case, createClassName returns an Object (Object.fromEntries() returns an Object).  Technically the typescript equivalent type that className has is { [key: string]: string }. In other words, className receives its type automatically anyways.

Comment: What is the result you're seeking?

Comment: @jperl className.[adminLoginpage,dashboard,....]

Comment: @uranshishko i add the example to show how i won't

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is possible because the TypeScript compiler doesn't execute code, it just transforms it. I think you need to hardcode the strings as a new type.

Comment: @Armen I think I understand what you are trying to acheive. Since the resulting type from createClassName is { [key: string]: string } you are unable to access for example className.adminLoginPage since according to TS it does not exist on className. What you do here is you make an if check beforehand to insure that it does exist. That way typescript won't throw an error. Eg. if(className.adminLoginPage) console.log(className.adminLoginPage);

Comment: @Armen another solution is to use non-null type assertion (i e the ! operator). Say that you have a function that takes a string as a parameter let test = (className: string) => /* do stuff here */. If you try to pass className.adminLoginPage as an argument to that function then typescript will complain, since className.adminLoginPage type is string | undefined. However if you pass it in as test(className.adminLoginPage!) or test(className.adminLoginPage as string) then it won't throw any error, because you are telling TS you know for sure it is a string.

Comment: @Armen how's it going? was my comment/solution helpful :)?

Comment: @uranshishko i hope that anyone give the code who worked... my english level in basic and translate don't work soo good )) i find variant to do it in russian stack overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [`ReturnType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype)?

```js
type c = ReturnType<typeof createClassName>
```

Comment: that's return [key:string]:string and don't give autocompile and error check

Comment: @olore that's posible ) see it's https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1279048/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8?noredirect=1#comment2253801_1279048